# Sorting alphanumeric text as alphabetically in Google Sheet

Tags: sorting, google-sheets

I have a Google Sheel Which Have alphanumeric text, as Can be seen in Picture
![Text]
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/lUs91.png)

I Want To sort All Rows with Custom Sort List as ("Wireless", "Landline", "VOIP"),

I tried following Function

'''
=LET(X,TOROW(A1:D1,1),SORTBY(X,FIND(MID(X,18,1),"WLV"),,X,))
'''
but it's Show Error

This error can be seen in this google sheet

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JbAsmYnqnr3WZ1-NJ_vhT-W6tTYqt7hmjQe_-aTrJlU/edit?usp=drivesdk

Please tell me the complete solution.
Make changes to the same Google Sheets if possible

Comment: Your [sample spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JbAsmYnqnr3WZ1-NJ_vhT-W6tTYqt7hmjQe_-aTrJlU/edit) is view-only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this formula in a free range in `Sheet2`, such as cell `Sheet2!AA2`:

```
=transpose( 
  sort( 
    transpose(L2:V2), 
    9 * regexmatch(transpose(trim(L2:V2)), "(?i)wireless"), false, 
    7 * regexmatch(transpose(trim(L2:V2)), "(?i)landline"), false, 
    5 * regexmatch(transpose(trim(L2:V2)), "(?i)voip"), false, 
    1 * regexmatch(transpose(trim(L2:V2)), "(?i)."), false 
  ) 
)
```

You can hide columns `L:V`, or replace their contents with the formula results by using copy and **Edit > Paste special > Values only**.